# Image is not loading using universal Image-loader in android

Tags: android, android-imageview, universal-image-loader

I have made an android app,In that in an activity I have one imageView,I want to display an image to it using imageLoader,I have been used so many time imageloader,But i got this type of error  **Image can't be decoded** ,My code is as below,Please help me for it,
**code**

```
iv_profile = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_profile);
imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(HomeActivity.this));

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheOnDisc(true).showStubImage(R.drawable.noimage).showImageOnFail(R.drawable.noimage).build();
String img = "http://tp.epagestore.in/" + Pref.getValue(HomeActivity.this, Const.PREF_PHOTO, "");
    imageLoader.displayImage(img, iv_profile, options);
```

Comment: see this issue https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/541

Comment: @QadirHussain-i have already gone thru it...only useless comments der..:!